# Java: Send List<String> via sockets

Tags: java, sockets, object, client-server

I want to send a list of strings from my client to server.

server

```
ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(connsock.getOutputStream());
public  List<String> current_clients_listening_songs = new ArrayList<String>();

current_clients_listening_songs.add("client 1 is listening to" + song);//song variable is string
//send list to client
objectOutput.writeObject(current_clients_listening_songs);
```

client

```
ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

//get list from server
Object get_client_listening = objectInput.readObject();

ArrayList<String> client_listening_songs = new ArrayList<String>();
//make a new list with server's list data
client_listening_songs = (ArrayList<String>) get_client_listening;
//print data
for (int i = 0; i < client_listening_songs.size(); i++) {

    System.out.println(client_listening_songs.get(i));
    }
```

server do add the item in list, but client doesnt get them, whats wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: yes it runs normally without errors

Comment: There is a lot that can go wrong and it is not clear from what you have posted. Is the client connected to the server? Can you send simple data (like single byte) from the server to the client? Does the server actually call `writeObject()`? Is the data actually send over the network? Does the client actually call `readObject()`. Does it return or throw? What does it return? Do you see any traffic on the network (you can use Wireshark or tcpdump for this)?

Comment: @rveerd yes to all, my client is connected to the server. and it can send data over the network. and yes it calls ```writeObject()```. is there any flush method in writeObject?

Comment: Not sure. There probably is such a call on the output streams or the underlying socket. You should use Wireshark or tcpdump to see what is actually send over the network.